# traversing folders, several subfolders for the files in python

Tags: python, glob, directory, subdirectory, os.walk

I've a folder structure similar to what's outlined below.

```
Path
|
|
+----SubDir1
|       |
|       +---SubDir1A
|       |       |
|       |       |----- FileA.0001.ext
|       |       |----- ...
|       |       |----- ...
|       |       |----- FileA.1001.ext
|       |       |----- FileB.0001.ext
|       |       |----- ...
|       |       |----- ...
|       |       |----- FileB.1001.ext
|       +---SubDir1B
        |
|       |       |----- FileA.0001.ext
|       |       |----- ...
|       |       |----- ...
|       |       |----- FileA.1001.ext
|       |       |----- FileB.0001.ext
|       |       |----- ...
|       |       |----- ...
|       |       |----- FileB.1001.ext
+----SubDir2
|       |
|       |----- FileA.0001.ext
|       |----- ...
|       |----- ...
|       |----- FileA.1001.ext
|       |----- FileB.0001.ext
|       |----- ...
|       |----- ...
|       |----- FileB.1001.ext
```

I want to be able to list the first FileA and first FileB for each SubDir1 and SubDir2

I've looked online and seen os.walk in a for loop, similar to:

```
import os

rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
    # Remove the first entry in the list of sub-directories
    # if there are any sub-directories present
    if len(subdirList) > 0:
        del subdirList[0
```

But that seems to only work if there's a file directly inside a subdirectory. My problem is that sometimes there's an additional subdirectory inside the subdirectory(!!)

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You said `I've looked online and seen os.walk in a for loop, similar to`. So do you mean the code you put in the question is not the code you ran?

Comment: No. i've used this code and tinkered with other code that also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is actually those two lines, remove them and you sould be fine:

```
if len(subdirList) > 0:
    del subdirList[0]
```

**Explanation** :

What they do is **they make the first subdirectory inside each directory disappear before `os.walk` had time to walk it**. So it is not surprising that you get weird behaviour regarding subdirectories.

Here's an illustration of that behaviour using the following tree :

```
test0/
├── test10
│   ├── test20
│   │   └── testA
│   ├── test21
│   │   └── testA
│   └── testA
├── test11
│   ├── test22
│   │   └── testA
│   ├── test23
│   │   └── testA
│   └── testA
└── testA
```

**Without** the problematic lines:

```
Found directory: ./test/test0
    testA
Found directory: ./test/test0/test10
    testA
Found directory: ./test/test0/test10/test21
    testA
Found directory: ./test/test0/test10/test20
    testA
Found directory: ./test/test0/test11
    testA
Found directory: ./test/test0/test11/test22
    testA
Found directory: ./test/test0/test11/test23
    testA
```

**With** the problematic lines:

```
Found directory: ./test/test0
    testA
Found directory: ./test/test0/test11
    testA
Found directory: ./test/test0/test11/test23
    testA
```

So we clearly see that the two subfolders `test10` and `test22` that were first in line have been ignored altogether because of the "bad lines".